# Beamer Frankfurt/Smoothbars Remove Shadow/Shading

Tags: beamer, header-footer, shading

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-0bp,rounded=false]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=false,shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]

removes the shadows from the frametitle, title page, etc..

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in head}[shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{section in head}[shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{beamercolorbox}[shadow=false]
```

Did not help. :(

I wan to get rid of the shadow/shading in the upper slide.

[image: I wan to get rid of the shadow/shading in the upper slide.]

Answer (score 2):

You need a redefinition of the `beamer@barshade` shading used by the smoothbars outer theme (original definition can be found in `beamerouterthemesmoothbars.sty`):

```
\documentclass[ ]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@barshade}{\the\paperwidth}{%
         color(0ex)=(black);%
         color(0.5ex)=(section in head/foot.bg);%
         color(4ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
       }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]